# Combining and adding like results

Tags: mysql

I have searched all over trying to find away when multiple like records are retrieved I need to add together 1 field. My query and results below.

This is my query:

```
SELECT m.id as 'id', m.name as 'Merchant Name', c.numStamps as 'Num Stampts on Card', COUNT(c.numStamps) as '# Users with this # Stampts'
FROM Merchants m, Cards c, Stores s
WHERE c.store_id = s.id
AND s.merchant_id = m.id
and c.redeemed = 0
and c.Numstamps>8
and c.datelaststamp > '2011-07-16 07:00:00'
group by m.id, c.numStamps
order by m.name, c.numStamps
```

These are the results:

```
id Merchant Name Stampts UserStampts

391 360 Gourmet Burritos 9 3
391 360 Gourmet Burritos 10 6
```

I need to combine `id` and `Merchant Name`. `Stampts` does not really matter but I need to add together `UserStampts`. So I need the return to be:

```
391 360 Gourmet Burritos 10 9
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to modify the query would be to turn it into a nested query:

```
SELECT id, Merchant, SUM(Stampts) AS Stampts, SUM(UserStampts) AS UserStampts
FROM ( ... your old query goes here ... ) AS oldquery
GROUP BY id, Merchant;
```

This will sum both columns (independently).

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT m.id as 'id', m.name as 'Merchant Name', c.numStamps as 'Num Stampts
on Card', COUNT(c.numStamps) as '# Users with this # Stampts'

FROM Merchants m, Cards c, Stores s

WHERE c.store_id = s.id

AND s.merchant_id = m.id

and c.redeemed = 0

and c.Numstamps>8

and c.datelaststamp > '2011-07-16 07:00:00'

group by m.id

order by m.name, c.numStamps
```

Comment: Grouping just by the m.id was all I needed. How things can be so simple sometimes. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to group by the name as well:

```
group by m.id, m.name, c.numStamps
```